# How to open file from git repository in sublime text (Mac)?

Tags: html, git, macos, sublimetext3

How can I open an html file from a cloned git repository on Sublime Text on Mac? I've tried the `subl` command but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the whole project from a terminal. Just follow the instructions here https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html

You have to run this command before

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Clone you repo and after that do:

```
cd <project_dir> && subl ./
```